# Java NoSuchMethodError printing methods

Tags: java

I am trying to print out the information on methods of a class. I thought it would be simple but im getting the described error everytime i run the program. Im not sure if i should post all my code here but Ill try to give you whats relevant. So i have a method in a class custom class that will print out all the methods in that class, here:

```
static void displayMethodInfo(Object obj)
    {
        Class<? extends Object> c = obj.getClass();
        Method methods[] = c.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method m : methods)
        {
            if(!Modifier.isPrivate(m.getModifiers())) 
            {
                String method = m.toGenericString();
                System.out.println(method);
            }
        }

    }
```

And i called it by:

```
Watch w = new Watch();
Watch.displayMethodInfo(w);
```

In the main. Any idea whats causing it?

Comment: Post the entire error message.

Comment: Sorry it says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: watch.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V

Comment: Your code works just fine. When you debug it, what method can't it find?

Comment: Your code is not the problem. You are having classpath problems.

Comment: What is a classpath problem?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I'd rather think he has "I have not written the main method"-problem.

Comment: Show us your `main` method!

Comment: And you're running it how?

Comment: on a linux server, compiled with javac watch.java, ran with java watch

Comment: Why `java watch`? You need to run `java MethodInfoTest`

Comment: Look at the OP and you will see why. Its not the prettiest i know

Comment: You should either stick to easy things, or learn what it means when you do it this way. Try `java 'Watch$MethodInfoTest'` BTW, there is no real reason to have main() in an extra class. And I am not certain you  are fooling us --- for, upon receipt of that error message, how could it not come to your mind that it **may** have to do with your funny arrangement of classes?

Comment: Guys i have tried every which way to simplify and combine and run this code but I am still getting the error, even doing what you said Ingo.

Comment: @user3055438 What is the error message with `java 'Watch$MethodInfoTest'` ?

Comment: word for word same error. I have no clue.

Comment: You did enter the apostrophes, didn't you?

Comment: By the way, that code you posted doesn't even compile.

Comment: Oh I... no i didnt, ive never run it that way before. It worked that time, thank you. However I agree its unnecessary to make the main like that. How would you recommend i format it so I can run with java WatcH?

Answer (score 1):

"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError watch.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V" implies you have set "Watch" as  a main class, but your sample shows that "MethodInfoTest" is the main class. You are trying to run a class with no main method :-)

Comment: Funny thing is, if the class is named "Watch" then "watch" should not available in the first place. Looks like old class files lying around there.